# Install Python setuptools on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, python, setuptools

I'm trying to install setuptools with no success so far.
When I do

```
python3.3 ez_setup.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Extracting in /tmp/tmp6nn4cz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 370, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "ez_setup.py", line 367, in main
    return _install(tarball, _build_install_args(options))
  File "ez_setup.py", line 55, in _install
    tar = tarfile.open(tarball)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/tarfile.py", line 1571, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

I've been reading and it seems that zlib-devel was not installed when the python installation was done.
However, I did uncomment line 358 on Modules/Setup to enable zlib before compiling and if I try to

```
import zlib
```

on python3.3 console it works.
Also, in case it helps, here is the ldd python3.3:

```
# ldd `which python3.3`
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff79fda000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b96092da000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b96094f6000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b96096fa000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b96098fe000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b9609b12000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b9609d95000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b96090bc000)
```

What can I do?

Comment: did you compile python3.3 without zlib-devel available?

Comment: The error `"tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully"` says that the file downloaded by ez_setup.py is not accessible. Possibly either you are behind any firewall/proxy which is not letting it download properly. You may download these files manually and try installing it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem as you (no idea why), after installed zlib-devel then compiled Python 3.3.2 into /usr/local.

As a workaround, the easiest way to get setuptools is just to:

```
# wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-1.1.6.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
# tar xf setuptools-1.1.6.tar.gz
# cd setuptools-1.1.6
# python3.3 setup.py install
```

Change the versions to your own versions.

Answer (score 1):

yum -y update

## Let's download the installation file using wget:

wget --no-check-certificate https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-1.4.2.tar.gz

## Extract the files from the archive:

tar -xvf setuptools-1.4.2.tar.gz

## Enter the extracted directory:

cd setuptools-1.4.2

## Install setuptools using the Python we've installed (2.7.6)

python2.7 setup.py install